# Accessing local string via EBP

Tags: assembly, stack, 32-bit

I am a new learner and I don't write in english well. I read from many sources that to access local variable in a procedure, first local is accessed using `[ebp-4]`. I make this program to display `EAX`, and only one data (`string`) local. What happen is `[ebp-4]` didn't work. I changed to [ebp-8] and it work. Why so?

```
        mov     eax,0x0ffffc345
        push    eax
        call    Disp_EAX
        call    exit

Disp_EAX:
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp,esp
        sub     esp,12   ;for string to display EAX
        cld
        lea     edi,[ebp-8] ;why can't [ebp-4]?
        mov     esi,8
        mov     edx,[ebp+8]
        mov     eax,0
extract:
        shld    eax,edx,4
        add     al,0x30
        cmp     al,0x39
        jle     continue
        add     eax,7
continue:
        stosb
        dec     esi
        cmp     esi,0
        je      done
        rol     edx,4
        xor     al,al
        jmp     extract
done:
        mov     eax,0
        stosb
        lea     esi,[ebp-8]
        cinvoke printf,esi
        add     esp,12
        mov     esp,ebp
        pop     ebp
        ret
```

Hope you can help me understand.

Addition: If I used `[ebp-4]`, my program loop continuously but display correctly. I am really confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack grows downwards on x86. If you set up a standard stack frame, `ebp` points to one past the end of your local variables, which start at the current value of `esp`. As such, you have `ebp`-`esp` bytes of locals.

You allocate 12 bytes using `sub esp, 12` so the address of that block is `ebp-12`. In the loop you use 8 bytes of that block. If you start from `ebp-8` you are writing `ebp-8` through `ebp-1` and all is fine, that is inside your block of locals. If you use `ebp-4` you are writing from `ebp-4` to `ebp+3` which is not good, since the last 4 bytes are not in your block allocated for the local variables. You will be overwriting the saved `ebp` on the stack that has been put there by the `push ebp` and that will cause unforeseeable problems.

Comment: Thank u for the good explantation Jester. So that means the access to local data dont always start from [ebp-4]. That was very confusing reading from some web materials.  That keep saying that. or it is just me who get that totally wrong.

Comment: Local data ends at `ebp`. The first local, if it is a 4 byte integer, is at `ebp-4`, but the second is at `ebp-8` as stack grows down. Locals occupy a memory region ending at `ebp`, starting at `esp` which is some negative offset (the size of all the locals) from `ebp`.

Comment: Yes. i find out that most reference assume the local data to be 4-byte. very rare I find ee i find examples using string of some size larger. i think that what causes the confusion. 4-byte is like a de facto standard for stack examples. Thanks again